# GWT DataGrid drop between rows

Tags: gwt, datagrid, drag-and-drop

We're using the [gwtquery-plugins](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers) and I'll be saying data grid referring to DragAndDropDataGrid for simplicity reasons.

We need a data grid catching drop events between rows. Data grid has `addDropHandler()` method, but this only gets called if the draggable is dropped over a cell. Dropping it between rows is like dropping an object outside the grid, has no effect. I guess this has to do with html spaces, that are not the grid itself.

Can this be accomplished? We wouldn't really want to go down the road in which We have to add dndWidgets between each row.